# iOS : Issue with dragging an object 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I need to drag an object around the screen , the problem is when I am dragging this object it could be dragged out of the iPhone/iPad' screen , how  can I avoid this situation here is my code :

```
  float startingX;
    float startingY;


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    startingX = [touch locationInView:self.view].x;
    startingY = [touch locationInView:self.view].y;
}




- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


    CGPoint currentPoint = objectView.frame.origin;
    float xForView, yForView;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    float newX = [touch locationInView:self.view].x;
    float deltaX;
    if(startingX > newX){
        deltaX = startingX - newX;
        xForView = currentPoint.x - deltaX;
    } else if(newX > startingX){
        deltaX = newX - startingX;
        xForView = currentPoint.x + deltaX;
    } else xForView = currentPoint.x;

    float newY = [touch locationInView:self.view].y;
    float deltaY;
    if(startingY > newY){
        deltaY = startingY - newY;
        yForView = currentPoint.y - deltaY;
    } else if(newY > startingY){
        deltaY = newY - startingY;
        yForView = currentPoint.y + deltaY;
    } else yForView = currentPoint.y;

    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(xForView, yForView, objectView.frame.size.width, objectView.frame.size.height);
    objectView.frame = newFrame;

    startingX = newX;
    startingY = newY;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add a handler in your touchmove function such as :

```
    if(currentPoint.x < 0) //which means it already moved out of your window 
{   
[yourObject setFrame:CGRectMake(0, currentPoint.y, yourObject.frame.size.width, yourObject.frame.size.height)];
} 
if(currentPoint.y < 0) //preventing your object goes upward beyond window 
{   
[yourObject setFrame:CGRectMake(currentPoint.x, 0, yourObject.frame.size.width, yourObject.frame.size.height)];
}
```

and do so also with if(currentPoint.y > self.view.frame.size.width) and height, so that the object wont go beyond your window on the lower side and right side

good luck

Comment: sorry for the long answer, you should put it in your touchesMoved method, so that the handler will always check if the object is out of bounds while you're dragging it

Comment: yeah I know I mean where exactly in touchesMoved ?  because I put this lines and nothing happens

Comment: you can add it before your CGRect newFrame, but be sure to add a conditional function if, so that it reads if your object out of bounds, it runs the code i give you, if not, it sets your object's frame to the current location of your touch

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the `frame` property of a view is in its superview's coordinate system. Also you could just set the `center` property of your view if you want only to move it (it's also in it's superview's coordinate system). Here is the algoritm to do it: in `touchesBegan:` method you get the coordinates and calculate the offset according to the center of the view, then in touchesMoved you just set the center of the view taking in mind the offset.